# FOSUserBundle email reset link not directing to correct page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony v2.6.13 and `FOSUserBundle`.

I am using FOSUserBundle to implement user authentication on my project.  I am using my own templates (twigs) to display `login/register/reset` password etc. by overriding their templates (i.e. placing the same file names into my `Project/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views` folder).  As documented here: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

The problem I am facing is the link that I receive via email to reset my password takes me back to the same page as I originally was i.e. the screen to enter my email/username.  The generated link in the email should be taking me to a screen which has two text boxes for me to change my password, but I never see this page.

I am out of ideas upon why this is occurring.

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: mongodb # other valid values are 'orm' mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Document\User
    registration:
        form:
            # using this because I am running Symfony 2.6
            type: app_user_registration
    resetting:
        token_ttl: 0    # no restrictions on resetting password
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        Brendan@stackoverflow.com
                sender_name:    SenderName
    service:
        #default implementation, and uses Swiftmailer to send emails.
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.default
```

So in the email it will generate a reset link such as this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/resetting/reset/59wonV9cK7UPR122rhNZQAXMJwoXUz7dt23_O-a4aJ4`

(Note: testing on local machine).

When I click the link it will take me to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/resetting/reset
```

Which subsequently is the screen that only gives me the option to enter my username or email to reset the password (i.e. the same screen looped).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I'm using the routes supplied by FOSUserBundle and annotations for my own routes.

app/config/routing.yml:

```
app_website:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
app:
   resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

And when checking my routes ($ php app/console route:debug) they are all default from FOSUserBundle:

```
 fos_user_security_login           GET|POST ANY    ANY  /login                            
 fos_user_security_check           POST     ANY    ANY  /login_check                      
 fos_user_security_logout          GET      ANY    ANY  /logout                           
 fos_user_profile_show             GET      ANY    ANY  /profile/                         
 fos_user_profile_edit             GET|POST ANY    ANY  /profile/edit                     
 fos_user_registration_register    GET|POST ANY    ANY  /register/                        
 fos_user_registration_check_email GET      ANY    ANY  /register/check-email             
 fos_user_registration_confirm     GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirm/{token}         
 fos_user_registration_confirmed   GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirmed               
 fos_user_resetting_request        GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/request                
 fos_user_resetting_send_email     POST     ANY    ANY  /resetting/send-email             
 fos_user_resetting_check_email    GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/check-email            
 fos_user_resetting_reset          GET|POST ANY    ANY  /resetting/reset/{token}          
 fos_user_change_password          GET|POST ANY    ANY  /profile/change-password
```

Comment: Can you show the routing.yml for your login/reset related routes.

Comment: I'm using the routes supplied by FOSUserBundle and annotations for my own routes.


app/config/routing.yml:
    `app_website:
        resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /
    app:
       resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
        type:     annotation
    fos_user:
        resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"`

Sorry hard to read, I edited my original post @Twifty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the `token_ttl` being set to 0 meant that the token was expired immediately so the user was never able to reset their password.  I initially set this to 0 to bypass the 'only reset your password once every 24 hours' with FOSUserBundle, however this was incorrect.

Removing this line fixed my issue.